# Cannot schema bind function Function because it references system object 'sys.extended_properties'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create an `Indexed View` in which I have used a Function named `GetBranchId`.

As far as I know, for creating an `Indexed View` we have to create the used functions with `SchemaBinding` as well. But the problem is when I want to Alter my function I get this error:

> Cannot schema bind function 'dbo.GetBranchId' because it references
>   system object 'sys.extended_properties'

**This is my Function:**

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBranchId] 
(
)
RETURNS smallint with schemabinding
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT TOP 1 CAST(value as smallint) 
     FROM sys.extended_properties Where class = 0 and name = 'BranchId')
END
```

Comment: You can't do this. No workaround except stop trying to use `sys.extended_properties` in an indexed view.

Comment: So can I get my Database Extended Property in any other way?

Comment: Sure, store these properties in your own user table, instead of using extended properties, which are kind of a second-class citizen in SQL Server anyway.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you would want to include this function in your indexed view anyway. Isn't it going to return the same value for every row in the view? Why not just pull this in the queries that reference the view, or create a non-indexed view that includes it in a cross join with the indexed view?

Comment: Although I don't know why I got a vote down. but anyway. @AaronBertrand I am not sure but according to MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx) I think you can not use a non-indexed view (which is not Schema Bounded) in an Indexed View. this is what I have understood from this Article

Comment: I think you misinterpreted. I meant `CREATE VIEW dbo.NonIndexedView AS SELECT iv.*, dbo.function() FROM dbo.IndexedView;` - but I still fail to see the point, when it will be the same value for every row!

Comment: Would also be curious to see the definition of the indexed view. Often people use indexed views as some kind of blind attempt to improve performance, but they're implemented incorrectly and/or for the wrong reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, say you have an indexed view (not "index view") like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.IndexedView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT ...
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON dbo.IndexedView(...);
GO
```

If you want to add a column to that view that represents this function, which pulls data from a catalog view, you can't use `SCHEMABINDING`, as you already know. So just create a different view, e.g.:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.NonIndexedView
AS
  SELECT iv.col1, iv.col2, BranchId = dbo.GetBranchId()
    FROM dbo.IndexedView;
```

However, as I mentioned in the comments, I fail to see the point. Since this is going to return a single value for every single row in the view, why not just get the value once, store it in a variable, and return it in the eventual query that queries the view?

Comment: I think that is a good solution. But you are right. I think I fail to see the point too. I have to reconsider why I have done that at all. Thanks for your help anyway.